# Add the image and path to the database for the specific users

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Extract Image File Name.
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        //Set the Image File Path.
        string filePath = "~/Uploads/" + fileName;

        //Save the Image File in Folder.
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        string mycon = "server =localhost; Uid=root; password = ; persistsecurityinfo = True; database =ovs; SslMode = none";

        MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(mycon);
      //  string sql = "INSERT INTO candidate VALUES(@Name, @Path)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO candidate(candidateImage,path where studentID ='" + Session["UserName"] + "') VALUES (@Name,@Path)", con1);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", fileName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", filePath);
        con1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con1.Close();
    }
```

When the users click the upload button, the image and path will be saved to the database that belongs to the specific users. For example, the users with ID R1001 login into their account, and when they click the upload button, the picture and path will be saved under the R1001 in the database. I show the error message which suggests there is a syntax error, but I not able to find it

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcWYU.png)

Comment: what is your error messege?

Comment: It says there is a syntax error at cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO candidate(candidateImage,path where studentID ='" + Session["UserName"] + "') VALUES (@Name,@Path)", con1);

Comment: why you in (candidateImage,path where studentID ='" + Session["UserName"] + "') where in insert time?

Comment: StudentID              Name    Path
R1001                                                                                                                                       The current database will look like this, my intention is when the users click the upload button, the name and path will be added.                                                                                    StudentID              Name                           Path
R1001                    image1                       uploads/ images1

Comment: Share you table schema.I mean tables's fields in order to know which fields are required

Comment: student have 1 photo or more photos?

Comment: each student will only have 1 photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `Where` when you want to insert data into your table.
I removed `where` in your `command` and used a parameter for sessionId.

```
     protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Extract Image File Name.
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        //Set the Image File Path.
        string filePath = "~/Uploads/" + fileName;

        //Save the Image File in Folder.
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        string mycon = "server =localhost; Uid=root; password = ; persistsecurityinfo = True; database =ovs; SslMode = none";

        MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(mycon);
        //  string sql = "INSERT INTO candidate VALUES(@Name, @Path)";
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string command = "update candidate set candidateImage=@Name ,path = @Path where StudentID=@studnetId";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, con1);
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", fileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", filePath);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studnetId", Session["UserName"]??""); // if student id is accept number in database, you must convert it to int
        con1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con1.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You misspelled `@studentId` and put in `@Name` twice instead of `@Path` though.

Comment: There is 3 column in the database, StudentID, name, and path. The studentID R1001 already exist in the database, the name and path haven't. When the user click the upload button, would like to store the name and path under the studentID R1001

Comment: @KekwYc Either you're updating a line and use a WHERE, or you're adding a new one and do not add a WHERE. But as osman Rahimi said, there is no such thing as an Insert with a WHERE clause.

Comment: @KekwYc So you need and update. is there always a record for user?

Comment: I change the command as update :  cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE SET candidate(candidateImage,path where studentID ='" + Session["UserName"] + "') VALUES (@Name,@Path)", con1);, but it still showing the error message saying syntax error

Comment: @KekwYc see my update command. and also share a photo of your table.

Comment: There is always a record for the StudentID, when the user click the upload button, the path and name will now be added based on the studentID (which I used the session to capture it when the user login)

Comment: what is the type of `studentID`  in database?

Comment: the studentID will be varchar

Comment: I updated my answer, please use my command to update.